# Android Manifest merge failed in Unity3D

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

The AndroidManifest is failing to merge. I have gone into the .xml files and fixed the minSdkVersion numbers but every time I attempt to build, they revert back to the original numbers and the build fails.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that FB sdk uses min sdk 15.

You should use `android:minSdkVersion="15"` if you want to use Facebook SDK.